# When we already have events in our application, why would we may need Event Sourcing?

Tags: events, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have gone through a lot of links and information about Event Sourcing and CQRS as well. But still, don't understand their proper need. What I could deduce is, it definitely brings complexity and scalability issues.

http://eventuate.io/whyeventsourcing.html

https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html

Comment: "definitely brings ... scalability issues." - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 4):

For me, the main benefit is an ability to refactor your domain model over time.

With ORM you very often end up with database structure that is not easy to change. After several years, the cost of database structure change and data migration could be prohibitive.

With Event Sourcing, your read models are calculated from event stream. You just create a new projection function and have a new database (your read model).

And there a lot of other benefits explained in [classic Greg Young's presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHGkaShoyNs).

Answer (score 1):

Requirements for event sourcing tend to look like requirements for a source control system

- we need the capability to recover data that was over written
- we need to be able to support temporal queries, meaning that we need to be able to answer questions about how the domain model looked in the past.

A dual way of thinking about it:

- we need the ability to audit every change in the model, but the model is too complicated to backup the entire data set after every change

In other words, what business value could you add if your data model was stored in git's object database?